# Layout spacing issue in a bigger size screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Does anyone know why this is happening:

The letters boxes are not aligned correctly in the tablet screen which is 10" but it works just fine on 7" and 4.7" screen.

[image]

Here is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/alphabetPad" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rowABCD"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnA"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="A"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnB"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="B"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnC"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="C"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnD"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="D"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rowEFGH"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnE"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="E"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="F"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnG"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="G"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnH"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="H"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/rowIJKL">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnI"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="I"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnJ"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="J"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnK"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="K"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnL"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="L"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/rowMNOP">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnM"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="M"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnN"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="N"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnO"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="O"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnP"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="P"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/rowQRST">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnQ"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Q"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnR"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="R"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnS"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="S"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnT"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="T"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/rowUVWX">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnU"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="U"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnV"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="V"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnW"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="W"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnX"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="X"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/rowYZ">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnBlank"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=""
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnY"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Y"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnZ"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Z"
                android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnBlank"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=""
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am guessing the boxes are too big to fit. How can I make it so that no matter what screen size the app is being displayed on, the boxes always line up.

I tried changing the margin for each button, 1dp for larger screen and 2dp for smaller screen but that didn't help.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace

```
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
```

with

```
android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
```

Try the below layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/alphabetPad" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rowABCD"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnA"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="A"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnB"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="B"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnC"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="C"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnD"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="D"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rowEFGH"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnE"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="E"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnF"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="F"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnG"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="G"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnH"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="H"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/rowIJKL">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnI"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="I"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnJ"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="J"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnK"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="K"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnL"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="L"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/rowMNOP">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnM"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="M"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnN"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="N"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnO"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="O"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnP"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="P"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/rowQRST">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnQ"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Q"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnR"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="R"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnS"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="S"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnT"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="T"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/rowUVWX">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnU"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="U"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnV"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="V"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnW"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="W"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnX"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="X"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/rowYZ">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnBlank"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnY"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Y"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnZ"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Z"
            android:background="@drawable/letterstyle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnBlank"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Please check the modified layout I just posted in my answer. It is working fine for me when I tested. When you are specifying layout_weight in a linear layout, it is always better to use layout_width or layout_height as fill_parent, as the LinearLayout adjusts the layout according to the layout_weight attribute, regardless of the content inside the layout.

Let me know if it works for you too!

Comment: You just wrote "replace X with X"? Are you certain this is what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TableLayout with android:stretchColumns="*" to force all columns to have the exact same width.

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button android:text="A"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="B"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="C"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="D"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="E"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button android:text="F"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="G"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="H"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="I"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="J"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button android:text="K"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="L"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="M"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="N"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="O"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button android:text="P"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Q"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="R"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="S"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="T"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: it makes the E smaller than A

Comment: Interesting. In that case, take a look at TableLayout. It allows you to specify that you want equal width columns. My answer has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: See example the example I added.

Comment: I got this idea from Big Nerd Ranch's Android Guide. Chapter 26 recommends using a TableLayout when displaying calculator keys, which is very similar to what you are doing.

Comment: The issue with TableLayout, I have to assign the Height if the screen size gets larger. With the current layout the height and width matches the screen but just not aligned properly.

Comment: Not true. You can use layout_weight="1" on all the TableRows. And you can use layout_height="match_parent" on all the Buttons. See updated example.

Comment: @ZahidH Please check the layout I posted. It should work fine for all the screens.

Comment: Thanks for the help, although TableLAyout did not solve the issue I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @BrianAttwell AAAhhhhhh I see now.